# python unique string creation

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I've looked at several other SO questions (and google'd tons) that are 'similar'-ish to this, but none of them seem to fit my question right.

I am trying to make a non fixed length, unique text string, only containing characters in a string I specify. E.g. made up of capital and lower case a-zA-Z characters. (for this example I use only a, b, and c lower case)

Something like this (broken code below)

```
def next(index, validCharacters = 'abc'):
    return uniqueShortAsPossibleString
```

The index argument would be an index (integer) that relate to a text string, for instance:

```
next(1)  == 'a'
next(2)  == 'b'
next(3)  == 'c'

next(4)  == 'aa'
next(5)  == 'ab'
next(6)  == 'ac'

next(7)  == 'ba'
next(8)  == 'bb'
next(9)  == 'bc'

next(10) == 'ca'
next(11) == 'cb'
next(12) == 'cc'
```

And so forth. The string:

1. Must be unique, I'll be using it as an identifier, and it can only be a-zA-Z chars
2. As short as possible, with lower index numbers being shortest (see above examples)
3. Contain only the characters specified in the given argument string validCharacters

In conclusion, how could I write the next() function to relate an integer index value to an unique short string with the characters specified?

P.S. I'm new to SO, this site has helped me tons throughout the years, and while I've never made an account or asked a question (till now), I really hope I've done an okay job explaining what I'm trying to accomplish with this.

Comment: Beware the iterative answers. While they may work, you have to store the state if you want to return where you left off without recomputing all previous values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to convert a number to a number in another base, but using arbitrary characters for the digits of that base.

```
import string
chars = string.lowercase + string.uppercase

def identifier(x, chars):
    output = []
    base = len(chars)
    while x:
        output.append(chars[x % base])
        x /= base
    return ''.join(reversed(output))

print identifier(1, chars)
```

This lets you jump to any position, you're counting so the identifiers are totally unique, and it is easy to use any character set of any length (of two or more), and lower numbers give shorter identifiers.

Comment: The `reversed` isn't even necessary here as you're worried only about length, not order.

Comment: Beware though: `identifier(123456789, chars)` returns `þƒžå`

Comment: Accepted (and +1'd?) this is exactly what I needed, and I appreciate the implementation. I knew it was something like this, just was unable to put a finger on it!

Comment: @JonClements What version of Python? Works fine for me on 2.7

Comment: agf: you're aware that your function never returns a string more than one character long starting with 'a', right? You can do a bit better, but you have to use a non-standard base system.

Comment: @JonClements odd, running identifier(123456789, chars), where chars is the same as agf's code.. I get "qUbfb" which seems correct to me.

Comment: @rici There was no requirement that it saturate the character space. You can also solve that specific problem by removing the `reversed`, though that just means you get `ab` instead of `ba`. Unless I knew the tiny amount of additional compactness mattered, I wouldn't write the more complex solution.

Comment: @JonClements I'm assuming you're in a non-english locale. If you want this to always be ASCII letters, you can use `string.ascii_letters` instead. What specific characters you use isn't really relevent, this is a general solution.

Comment: I changed it to use `ascii_lowercase` and `ascii_uppercase` and now it works - not on my own PC, so can't speak for settings... Although specifying ascii explicitly is probably better as OP did ask for a-zA-z

Comment: It says "as short as possible" and it could be almost 2% shorter. Add x-=1 at the top of the whileloop and start numbering identifiers at 1.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is write the parameter of the `next` function in another base.

Let's suppose `validCharacters` contains `k` characters: then the job of the `next` function will be to transform parameter `p` into base `k` by using the characters in `validCharacters`.

In your example, you can write the numbers in base 3 and then associate each digit with one letter:

```
next(1) -> 1 -> 'a'
next(2) -> 2 -> 'b'

next(4) -> 11 -> 'aa'
next(7) -> 21 -> 'ba'
```

And so forth.

With this method, you can call `next(x)` without knowing or computing any `next(x-i)`, which you can't do with iterative methods.

Comment: +1 for idea, I needed to see some sort of base implementation or psuedo code to understand it though.

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) can always give you obfuscated one-liner iterators:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement, chain

chars = 'abc'
a = chain(*(combinations_with_replacement(chars, i) for i in range(1, len(chars) + 1)))
```

Basically, this code creates an iterator that combines all combinations of `chars` of lengths `1`, `2`, ..., `len(chars)`.

The output of `for x in a:  print x` is:

```
('a',)
('b',)
('c',)
('a', 'b')
('a', 'c')
('b', 'a')
('b', 'c')
('c', 'a')
('c', 'b')
('a', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'c', 'b')
('b', 'a', 'c')
('b', 'c', 'a')
('c', 'a', 'b')
('c', 'b', 'a')
```

Comment: +1 for making me feel like a noob. I solved this problem the long way round a few months ago, it was a friggin mission :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't really "associate" the index with annoying, but the following is a generator that will yield and provide the output you're asking for:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

def uniquenames(chars):
    for i in range(1, len(chars)):
        for j in combinations_with_replacement(chars, i):
            yield ''.join(j)

print list(uniquenames('abc'))
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'bb', 'bc', 'cc']
```

Comment: @Blender Thanks, just realised it's missing some though... need to fix that

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood we shouldn't specify maximum length of output string. So `range` is not enough:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations_with_replacement, count
>>> def u(chars):
...     for i in count(1):
...         for k in combinations_with_replacement(chars, i):
...             yield "".join(k)
... 
>>> g = u("abc")
>>> next(g)
'a'
>>> next(g)
'b'
>>> next(g)
'c'
>>> next(g)
'aa'
>>> next(g)
'ab'
>>> next(g)
'ac'
>>> next(g)
'bb'
>>> next(g)
'bc'
```

Comment: @Blender I don't think in this case the iterative answers are solving the right problem.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like you are trying to enumerate through all the strings generated by the language {'a','b','c'}. This can be done using [finite state automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) (though you don't want to do that). One simple way to enumerate through the language is to start with a list and append all the strings of length 1 in order (so a then b then c). Then append each letter in the alphabet to each string of length n-1. This will keep it in order as long as you append all the letters in the alphabet to a given string before moving on to the lexicographically next string.

Comment: This problem is much, much simpler than that.